# export prepared table content to excel sheet in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I did some code, that is working on all browsers expect Edge...

Code:

```
   var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
   var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 
   if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./) || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge')>-1) {
    exportTable.document.open();
    exportTable.document.write(exportData);
    exportTable.document.close();
    exportTable.focus(); 
    sa = exportTable.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"exportData.xls");
    }
    else{
    sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(exportData));
    }
```

In the Edge Browser : 
Here i'm getting the problem...

```
exportTable.document.open();
```

HTML:

```
</div>
    <iframe id="exportTable" style="display:none"></iframe>
</div>
```

I did like this also :

```
var doc = exportTable.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(exportData);
....
```

But it wasn't work out..

what is the alternate for "iframe.documenet.open()" in Edge.??
how is it going to be supported for all browsers.??

And i didn't get the control over 'downloading file name' while downloading in chrome and firefox....

```
Note : I prepared that table manually by using javascript. I didnt use HTML for table preperation.. because i want to export some columns only based on the demand..
```

Comment: what does this code do ,what do you need to do, why use iframes?

Comment: Basically, i want to export selected columns from HTML table into Excel file and downloading that file.. i used this reference : [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/338e87/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/)